# Text argument from a dataframe

Tags: r

I try to test [this nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283368/8935521) using a dataframe as input in the your_sentence.

```
remove_words <- function(sentence, badword="blame"){
  tagged.text <- treetag(file=sentence, format="obj", treetagger="manual", lang="en", 
                         TT.options=list(path=":C\\Treetagger", preset="en"))
  # Check for bad words AND verb:
  cond1 <- (tagged.text@TT.res$token == badword)
  cond2 <- (substring(tagged.text@TT.res$tag, 0, 1) == "V")
  redflag <- which(cond1 & cond2)

  # If no such case, return sentence as is. If so, then remove that word:
  if(length(redflag) == 0) return(sentence)
  else{
    splitsent <- strsplit(sentence, " ")[[1]]
    splitsent <- splitsent[-redflag]
    return(paste0(splitsent, collapse=" "))
  }
}

lapply(your_sentences, remove_words)
```

The data frame has 1 column and 351 rows. In lapply in your_sentences I use the call for my dataframe and the column name and I receive this error (the same error is when I use the dataframe without call the column):

```
> dfnew <- lapply(df$text, remove_words)
 Error in writeLines(text, con = conn.tempfile) : invalid 'text' argument
```

What can I do to solve the error?

Example data:

```
df = data.frame(text = c('I blame myself for what happened', 'For what happened the blame is yours', 'I will blame you if my friend removes'))
```

Comment: Since the error tells you that something is wrong with your temporary files the first thing that caught my eye is that there might be a typo in your path: `path=":C\\Treetagger"`. The C should be followed not preceded by the colon.

Comment: @ManuelBickel thank you. I fixed it path="C:\\Treetagger" but unfortunately the error exist

Answer (score 2):

What a bummer, hoped that its only a typo :-). But I have a second guess. You probably stepped into the difficulties caused by `StringsAsFactors = TRUE`. This might have caused passing the type `factor` instead of `character` to your function. Try the following:

```
df = data.frame(text = c('I blame myself for what happened'
                         , 'For what happened the blame is yours'
                         , 'I will blame you if my friend removes')
                         , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your strings seem to be saved as factors and therefore `remove_words` is supplied with factor values, instead of strings. Using the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as an argument will solve the issue:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c('I blame myself for what happened', 
                         'For what happened the blame is yours', 
                         'I will blame you if my friend removes'), 
                stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Or, if you have already defined your `df` with factors, you can change that using `df <- lapply(df, as.character)`

```
lapply(df$text, remove_words)
[[1]]
[1] "I myself for what happened"

[[2]]
[1] "For what happened the blame is yours"

[[3]]
[1] "I will you if my friend removes"
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting via additional explanations. There is one little typo, you should use brackets in `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` in order to keep the `data.frame` structure. Otherwise a `list` is returned.

Comment: It works regardless, but I like thoughtful comments about improving details

Comment: Thanks, however, I disagree, it does not work regardless, try: `df = data.frame(A = c("x", "y"))
df <- lapply(df, as.character)
class(df)
#[1] "list"
df = data.frame(A = c("x", "y"))
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
class(df)
#[1] "data.frame"`

Comment: I saw your point. What I tried to say is that whether `df` is a list or a data.frame doesn't affect the result in my answer, because `lapply( ....)` works the same way in either case.

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was a misunderstanding. So we are both right :-).