# Filtering text from numbers and stopwords in R(not for tdm)

Tags: r, tm, tidytext

I have text corpus.

```
mytextdata = read.csv(path to texts.csv)
Mystopwords=read.csv(path to mystopwords.txt)
```

How can I filter this text? I must delete:

```
1) all numbers

2) pass through the stop words

3) remove the brackets
```

I will not work with `dtm`, I need just clean this textdata from numbers and stopwords

sample data:

```
112773-Tablet for cleaning the hydraulic system Jura (6 pcs.) 62715
```

`Jura,the` are stopwords.

In an output I expect

```
  Tablet for cleaning hydraulic system
```

Comment: Would you provide a sample data?

Comment: And the code you have tried so far, along with your expected result. This is a common text mining task, perhaps searching resources like [library(tidytext)](http://tidytextmining.com/) would get you going

Comment: @jazzurro, i edited post with sample data

Comment: @Nate, i edited post with that i expect

Comment: Do you need to remove anything in `()`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say, also remove the brackets

Comment: Do you have a data frame? Or do you just have multiple strings like your example?

Comment: not, only set with  multiple strings

Answer (score 6):

Since there is one character string available in the question at the moment, I decided to create a sample data by myself. I hope this is something close to your actual data. As Nate suggested, using the tidytext package is one way to go. Here, I first removed numbers, punctuations, contents in the brackets, and the brackets themselves. Then, I split words in each string using `unnest_tokens()`. Then, I removed stop words. Since you have your own stop words, you may want to create your own dictionary. I simply added `jura` in the `filter()` part. Grouping the data by id, I combined the words in order to create character strings in `summarise()`. Note that I used `jura` instead of `Jura`. This is because `unnest_tokens()` converts capital letters to small letters.

```
mydata <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                     text = c("112773-Tablet for cleaning the hydraulic system Jura (6 pcs.) 62715",
                              "1234567-Tablet for cleaning the mambojumbo system Jura (12 pcs.) 654321"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

data(stop_words)

mutate(mydata, text = gsub(x = text, pattern = "[0-9]+|[[:punct:]]|\\(.*\\)", replacement = "")) %>%
unnest_tokens(input = text, output = word) %>%
filter(!word %in% c(stop_words$word, "jura")) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(text = paste(word, collapse = " "))

#     id                              text
#  <int>                             <chr>
#1     1  tablet cleaning hydraulic system
#2     2 tablet cleaning mambojumbo system
```

Another way would be the following. In this case, I am not using `unnest_tokens()`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)
library(tidytext)

data(stop_words)

gsub(x = mydata$text, pattern = "[0-9]+|[[:punct:]]|\\(.*\\)", replacement = "") %>%
stri_split_regex(str = ., pattern = " ", omit_empty = TRUE) %>%
lapply(function(x){
    foo <- x[which(!x %in% c(stop_words$word, "Jura"))] %>%
           paste(collapse = " ")
    foo}) %>%
unlist

#[1] "Tablet cleaning hydraulic system"  "Tablet cleaning mambojumbo system"
```

Comment: it is possible to leave only the nouns and adjectives (if any) (Tablet  cleaning )

Comment: @D.Joe If you have a data set which includes words and lexical categories (e.g., noun, verb, and adjective), I think you can do that.

Comment: If you want to end up with a data set of only nouns and adjectives and want to work with tidy data, I would check out the cleanNLP package and do POS tagging with it.

Comment: @JuliaSilge I did not know the package before. I will check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this. If you want to rely on base R only, you can transform @jazurro's answer a bit and use `gsub()` to find and replace the text patterns you want to delete.

I'll do this by using two regular expressions: the first one matches the content of the brackets and numeric values, whereas the second one will remove the stop words. The second regex will have to be constructed based on the stop words you want to remove. If we put it all in a function, you can easily apply it to all your strings using `sapply`:

```
mytextdata <- read.csv("123.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

custom_filter <- function(string, stopwords=c()){
  string <- gsub("[-0-9]+|\\(.*\\) ", "", string)
  # Create something like:  "\\b( the|Jura)\\b"
  new_regex <- paste0("\\b( ", paste0(stopwords, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
  gsub(new_regex, "", string)
}

stopwords <- c("the", "Jura")
custom_filter(mytextdata[1], stopwords)
# [1] "Tablet for cleaning hydraulic system  "
```

Comment: it is possible to leave only the nouns and adjectives (if any) (Tablet  cleaning )

Comment: Yes, it is. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274691/remove-a-verb-as-a-stopword/47283368#47283368) of mine. Instead of *removing* verbs, you can adapt the answer a bit to only *keep* nouns and adjectives